# Use type_identity_t in a lambda argument

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, type-conversion

I'm trying to reimplement Logan Smith's `implicit_cast` from [Cursed C++ Casts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmlLdd1Q2V8) within an expression. My approach is to combine an anonymous function with `type_identity_t`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int i = 1;
  long j = 4;
  cout << max(j, []<class T>(type_identity_t<T> x) -> T { return x; }(i));
}
```

But it doesn't work. The compiler (gcc 13.2) complains:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:6:70: error: no match for call to '(main()::<lambda(std::type_identity_t<T>)>) (int&)'
    6 |   cout << max(j, []<class T>(type_identity_t<T> x) -> T { return x; }(i));
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
<source>:6:18: note: candidate: 'template<class T> main()::<lambda(std::type_identity_t<T>)>'
    6 |   cout << max(j, []<class T>(type_identity_t<T> x) -> T { return x; }(i));
      |                  ^
<source>:6:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:6:70: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
    6 |   cout << max(j, []<class T>(type_identity_t<T> x) -> T { return x; }(i));
      |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Is it salvageable? Or should I switch to some other approach?

Comment: C++ doesn't do template argument deduction based on how the return value is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the video explains this `implicit_cast` must be called with an explicit template argument specifying the target type. Your lambda call lacks that. The whole point of `type_identity_t<T>` is to make it so that `T` *won't* be deduced automatically. It is there to force the user to specify the template argument explicitly. It doesn't have any other functional effect.

To call the lambda with an explicit template argument you need to write

```
[]<class T>(type_identity_t<T> x) -> T { return x; }.operator()</*target type*/>(i)
```

Comment: Or I could write `decltype(j){i}`. I'm looking for the most general possible way in which the target type is somehow deduced, so that the code keeps working when a change of type occurs elsewhere.

Comment: @ByteEater `decltype(j){i}` is not the same, because it is direct-list-initialization instead of an implicit conversion. If you don't actually care about the specific initialization form used, then just `{i}` is enough. Braced-init-lists are not deduced from. This will however not be the same if you e.g. switch the types of `i` and `j`, because then it becomes a narrowing conversion, which is allowed as an implicit conversion in general, but specifically not in list-initialization.

Comment: You're right, that's equivalent for this specific case but yours with `.operator()` keeps the key characteristic of `implicit_cast`. But it requires mentioning the target type. What I meant to indicate would give, combined with your code: `[]<class T>(type_identity_t<T> x) -> T { return x; }.operator()<decltype(j)>(i)`.

Comment: @ByteEater Yes that works, but if you are going for generality, then note that the presented `implicit_cast` also has problems. For example it potentially makes an extra constructor call that a simple implicit conversion wouldn't do.

Comment: Converting constructor call of the target type when passing the argument to `implicit_cast`?

Comment: @ByteEater That's the intended one, but there will also be a move/copy constructor call into the return value. So it won't work for e.g. a type that isn't movable even though the normal implicit conversion of a function argument would work.